# Polymer handle click event from custom element child

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm new to Polymer , I have a dom-repat custom element that contains a simple-overlay ,I want when clicking close button this overlay should close

this is the custom element

```js
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<link rel="import" href="../overlay-layer/simple-overlay.html">

<dom-module is="feed-bdy">

   
    <template items="{{items}}">
       <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment" >  
      :host{
      --paper-button-ink-color: var(--paper-pink-a200);
        --paper-button{
          background-color: red !important;
          color: red;
        }

      }
      .custom{
        color: red;
      }
       .content-bdy{
        min-height: 120px;
        }
        .scrollable{
           @apply(--layout-scroll);
           max-width: 75%;
  
        }
    
   </style>
      <div class="card-content">
         <div class="ar-header">
            <h3><a href="#">  [[items.fields.title]]</a></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="content-bdy"></div>
      </div>
      [[_renderHTML(items)]]
      <div class="card-actions">
         <paper-button  class="custom" id="ar-[[items.fields.articleId]]" on-click="_openOverlay">إقراء المزيد !</paper-button>
         <simple-overlay id="backdrop-[[items.fields.articleId]]" data-ar="backdrop-[[items.fields.articleId]]" with-backdrop class="layout scrollable">
         
          [[_renderFullArticle(items)]]
        
          <button  id="dd">Close</button>
          </simple-overlay>
         <paper-button>
            شارك 
            <iron-icon icon="reply"></iron-icon>
         </paper-button>
      </div>

   </template>
  
   <script>
      Polymer({
       is: 'feed-bdy',
       listeners :{
        'dd.click':'_closeOverlay'
       },
       _renderHTML: function(items) {
        // firstp to get only the first pargarph to put in the home page
        var ss= items.fields.body;
        //console.log(this.$$(".card-content"));
        var firstp = ss.substring(0,ss.search("</p>")+4);
        this.$$(".content-bdy").innerHTML += firstp;
        
        
       },
       _renderFullArticle : function(items){
        this.$$("simple-overlay").innerHTML +=items.fields.body;

       },
       _toggle : function(e){
        var id = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.title;
        //console.log(id);
        var moreInfo = document.getElementById(id);
       // console.log(moreInfo);
        var iconButton = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget;
             iconButton.icon = moreInfo.opened ? 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-up'
                                               : 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-down';
            moreInfo.toggle();
       },
       _openOverlay : function(e){
        //console.log('calling _openOverlay');
        var id = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.id.split('ar-')[1];
        var dd = document.getElementById('backdrop-'+id);
        dd.open();
       },
       _closeOverlay : function(e){
        console.log(Polymer.dom(e));
        console.log('calling _openOverlay');
        var id = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.id.split('ar-')[1];
       // var dd = document.getElementById('backdrop-'+id);
       /// dd.close();
       }
      });
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

and in the index.html

```html
<div class="video layout horizontal around-justified wrap" >
                      
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]" >
    
  <paper-card image="[[item.fields.image]]" class="flex-auto" wide-layout$="{{wide}}">
          

         <feed-bdy items="[[item]]"></feed-bdy>
  </paper-card>
        </template>
      </div>
```

so when clicking the close button the _closeOverlay should be fired and I tried to console messages as you can see , but no event was fired any advice

Comment: Hate to say it but you got a lot of things going against in this code.  1.  you have your style tag in the template repeat.  2.  listeners don't work like how you've defined them.  3.  add an on-tap="_closeOverlay" event handler on your button element.  4. your card-actions element should most likely be a first class custom polymer element so in your closeOverlay you can do a selection on that simple-overlay element without having to "attach" meta data to target which overlay you are talking about.  Right now your close needs to be smart in knowing which overlay to target.

Comment: @getbuckts thanks for your answer , 1- I removed the style tag to the index
2- I've tried the all the different ways to receive the event but none worked
3-event with adding the on-tap handler no event was fired 
4-  I did not really understand what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You only show part of your index.html file, but is the content you did show inside a `<template is="dom-bind">` ?

Polymer doesn't work with databinding and events etc unless that stuff is.

These days (following Google I/O 2016) and the discussions about lazy loading etc I have stopped using the dom-bind approach and instead have a single custom element that then has all the functionality inside, including styling.

Comment: i did not want to put all the index file code this is the part where the content inserted , so any advice to fix this issue ??

Comment: @user3853257 - The template tag in my reply was hidden by stackoverflow's formatting.  Does it make more sense now